# "Access is denied" when consuming custom WCF Service

Tags: wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access denied when code is executed remotely as a wcf service](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35457/access-denied-when-code-is-executed-remotely-as-a-wcf-service)

I successfully deployed a simple wcf service on sharepoint. But when trying to consume it,i am getting `Access is denied` error. Stack trace below:

```
Access is denied.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

My **config** file at **client side** is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <windows allowNtlm="true" allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IConverterService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mysite/_vti_bin/converterservice/converterservice.svc"
            behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IConverterService"
            contract="SPConverterService.IConverterService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IConverterService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am using my windows login to access the sharepoint site.

My Service is really simple, as show below:

```
void Convert();
```

which starts a word automation conversion job.

**Solutions Tried:**

a)Tried wrapping the code inside

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate{ [code] })
```

But getting the same error.

b) Changed config to

```
<clientCredentials>
      <windows allowNtlm="false" allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
 </clientCredentials>
```

which is not working either.

**Update**

After some workingout, I figured out the config. is fine and is working. The actual problem is within my code

```
using (SPSite newspSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
     foreach (SPService service in newspSite.WebApplication.Farm.Services)
     {

             foreach (SPJobDefinition jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions)
             {

                  if (jobDefinition.Name == "Word Automation Services")
                  {
                         jobDefinition.RunNow();
                         break;
                  }

             }
      }
}
```

This code is giving problems as it is not possible to run `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration` methods remotely. The workarounds for this as mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2564009) is only working for `SPWebService` and is not available for `ConversionJob`.

Are there any alternatives???

Any help or pointers on how to resolve is highly appreciated.

Thank you.